# Script to open a webpage many times to test a server

Tags: connection, websocket

I would like to test my websocket sever to see home many open connections it can handle at the same time. 
To do that I can open many webpages manually and see if the server crashes or not. However, I am looking for an automatic way. Like a simple script that can loop through opening the URL many times.

Is there any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for web server stress testing tools.

[Jmeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) is a simple free tool that can do some performance/functional testing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running an Apache server you could use the Apache benchmark command-line tool.

So let's say for this instance that your server is running on localhost(127.0.0.1), port 8000. If we want to know whether the concurrent connections can be handled by the server we'd have to have a script that executes for a set amount of (mili)seconds and take the average of that.

So let's create a JavaScript function for your server that does a 1 second timeout like this:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
console.log("Executed")
}, 1000)
```

With the Apache command-line tools installed run the following command

> ab -n 100 -c 100 http://127.0.0.1:8000

If all goes well you should see the average time it has taken to execute a single script. The results should be somewhere between 1 and 1.1 seconds.

I would assume that you are using [NodeJS](http://www.nodejs.org/)? If not I would definitely recommend looking into it. Mostly because of it's non-blocking awesomeness.